# Cannot remove duplicate value from string

Tags: php

I want remove duplicate value from a string, so I'm using this code:

```
$new_order = '49850, 49850, 49851, 49852, 49853, 49854';
$new_order = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $new_order)));
```

output:

string(40) "49850, 49850, 49851, 49852, 49853, 49854"

but should be:

string(40) "49850, 49851, 49852, 49853, 49854"

Comment: Your implode/explode dance doesn't account for the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you explode on just a comma, the second value is `49850` (with an extra space at the start).

So explode on a comma followed by a space

```
$new_order = '49850, 49850, 49851, 49852, 49853, 49854';
$new_order = implode(',', array_unique(explode(', ', $new_order)));
```

or, you can add `array_map()` in there to `trim()` each entry...

```
$new_order = implode(',', array_unique(array_map('trim', explode(',', $new_order))));
```